# get .sfd SplineSet from existing PostScript1 font (fontforge)

Tags: fonts, postscript, fontforge

I have a .pfb font file. When I open a glyph using fontforge, I can see that it has Fore and Back Layers. How do I get the information to include in .sfd file about the SplineSet of that particular glyph ?

Is there an elaborate tutorial for beginners on the syntax for writing .sfd files, apart from https://fontforge.github.io/sfdformat.html ?

Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that saving it as a .sfd file works. Thanks.

Comment: that's great - is that an answer to this problem? (if so, post it as answer) or does that mean you should have held off asking this question for an hour longer? (if so, delete this question)